# Syntax error when creating stored function

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, stored-functions

I'm trying to write my very first stored function in MySQL 5.5.38, but I cannot get past an annoying syntax error. I already checked the MySQL docs, but I still can't see what the problem is and the error message only says `You have an error in your SQL syntax; blah blah blah ... at line 1`.

Here's the code:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION distm (lat1 DOUBLE, lng1 DOUBLE, lat2 DOUBLE, lng2 DOUBLE)
    RETURNS DOUBLE NO SQL DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE radius DOUBLE;
    SET radius = 6371008.771415059;

    DECLARE x1, y1, x2, y2, dlat, dlng DOUBLE;
    SET x1 = RADIANS(lng1);
    SET y1 = RADIANS(lat1);
    SET x2 = RADIANS(lng2);
    SET y2 = RADIANS(lat2);
    SET dlng = x2 - x1;
    SET dlat = y2 - y1;

    DECLARE dist DOUBLE;
    SET dist = 2 * radius * ASIN(
        SQRT(
            POW(SIN(dlat / 2), 2)
            + COS(y1) * COS(y2) * POW(SIN(dlng / 2), 2)
        )
    );
    RETURN dist;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

*EDIT:* The exact error message is the following:

```
SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION distm (lat1 DOUBLE, lng1 DOUBLE, lat2 DOUBLE, lng2' at line 1
```

Comment: Did you try after removing `DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS distm;` ?

Comment: It definitely doesn't say `blah blah blah` .. post the exact error if you want further help.

Comment: @Rahul You're right, I've added the exact error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `DROP` statement before `DELIMITER $$` and run again.

Also, change the line `RETURNS DOUBLE NO SQL DETERMINISTIC` to below. Notice, it's not `NO SQL DETERMINISTIC` rather `NOT DETERMINISTIC`

```
RETURNS DOUBLE NOT DETERMINISTIC
```

Comment: I removed the said statement from the code in my post. However the doc definitely says it's `NO SQL`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-procedure.html

Comment: Check the document again properly.

Comment: @3k- From the doc you link to: "**NO SQL** indicates that the routine contains no SQL statements." Although it's only advisory, I reckon your SP *does* contain SQL statements and therefore you should not use that characteristic anyway.

Comment: @3k- ... and you said you're using MySQL 5.5, whereas you linked to a doc for version 5.1 (although they say the same thing about `NO SQL`).

Comment: @AndrewMorton yes, I'm sorry. I just posted the first search result, because I was in a hurry. But if `DECLARE`, `SET`, `RETURN`, etc. are SQL statements then what is NOT an SQL statement in MySQL?